How to Disable an overlapping actor in ue5
My problem is that i have this overlapping actor when i overlap with it i take damage i want to disable it meaning i want the actor to stay in the scene and if i touch it i dont take damage and when the anger int goes over 6 it reenables making me take damage when i touch it a gain. why i need this is because i have a ghost i want the ghost to only attack when anger is over 6 the ghost uses the overlapping trigger box to damage the player currently i get damaged
I have tried using multiple methods of doing deactivate and activate, set active, everything, btw way i dont want to hide the actor the actor is already hidden

have you tried setting SetCollisionEnabled to NoCollision on the target actor's collision component?

OK, that didn't appear to work, this one seemed to work for me in an isolated example.


it dony think it will work because it uses overlaping but i will try

it didnt work sad

i added another node to the answer for you to try, i was able to stop overlaps in a sample project with that node.

i remmeber trying it but i can try again

i remmeber now why it didnt work

because my overlaping component is a child actor under the mesh so it can be attached to the socket of my ai

thanks for your help iv created a function in the actor that enables then disables the object i will post how i did for the people intrested on how to do it
